# Name Manager using VBA - Macro vs. Function Call Gives Different Response

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I have an XLA I'm use to make calculations and I'd like to create variables in the Name Manager to use in those calculations.  I want to check to see if those named ranged already exist and if not let the user assign values to them.  I have a Sub() that I'm using to set the Name Manager -example below- :

```
Public Sub SetNames()
On Error Resume Next
   IsRangeName = CheckName("test")

If IsRangeName = Empty Then
   Application.ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="test", RefersTo:=0
End If

End Sub
```

If I go into the "Macro" menu and run the SetNames routine it works and sets test = 0 in the Name Manager.

However, what I want to do is run this through a Function and allow the function to use the variables in the Name Manager if they exist, if they don't exist then those values get set to an initial value in the Name Manager through the subroutine.

When I try to run the following code the values are never set in the Name Manager:

```
Sub Function1()
   Call SetNames()

   -Do Other Things-

End Function
```

All of the names are declared as global variables.

The intent is to have a user install the add-in and on the first function call using the add-in the Name Manager gets set, either to initialize the names or to allow the user to set the initial value.  I don't want the user to go through the Macro ribbon option and execute the subroutine to initialize the Name Manager names.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Some actions cannot be performed from within a function called as a UDF: adding names is one of those actions

Comment: Tim - thanks for the insight.  Any thoughts about how to best execute my intent?  I'm trying to initialize several variables in the Name Manager when a user requests a function from my XLA.  I don't want to add names if the user just has the add-in loaded and isn't calling any functions and I don't want to have to tell the user to manually run the SetNames Sub through the Macro window.  These variables have an initial value, but need to be accessible to the user to change - so I don't want to hard code them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This **seems** to work in my quick testing, but you should be sure it performs in whatever your final use case is.  It's a hack around the restrictions on a UDF being able to update the workbook, so it's outside of "normal" usage.

```
Sub SetNameIfMissing(swb As String)

    Dim r As Name, wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks(swb)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = wb.Names("test")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If r Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "adding name..."
        wb.Names.Add "test", 99
    Else
        Debug.Print "already added"
    End If

End Sub


Function SetIt(v)

    Dim wb
    wb = Application.Caller.Parent.Parent.Name

    'using Evaluate gets around the UDF restriction
    Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate "SetNameIfMissing(""" & wb & """)"

    SetIt = "OK" 'or whatever return value is useful...

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what "CheckName" is in your script - you didn't provide it .. however, I got it to work via:

1) comment out On Error Resume Next - this allows you to see CheckNames failing.

2) Replaced CheckNames with a loop to loop throw the defined names, looking for ours.

3) change your "function" definition from "sub" to "function".

test it, runs fine.
Sets the "test" name if it doesn't exist. Change it manually to another value, run again, doesn't touch it.

```
  Public Sub SetNames()
  'On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To Application.ThisWorkbook.Names.Count
      If Application.ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name = "test" Then
         IsRangeName = True
         Exit For
      End If
    Next i

  If Not IsRangeName Then
     Application.ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="test", RefersTo:=1
  End If

  End Sub

  Function Function1()
     Call SetNames

     '-Do Other Things-

  End Function
```

Comment: I updated Function1() to return the value of test using Application.Evaluate().  If I start clean (ie. "test" does not exist), the cell I call Function1() from evaluates as #VALUE! because the sub never assigns "test" = 1 in the Name Manager.  If I run the sub from the macro window then call Function1() from the cell, it evaluates to 1.  Seems like Tim's comment above applies

Comment: Ahh, I see - you are trying to call the function from a cell?  Yeah, not sure that will work in this case ... if it does, I'm not entirely sure how to do it (yet). I'll fiddle when I get time - if somebody else doesn't manage to answer first. ;)